# GetTempFileName for metro apps

Tags: microsoft-metro

I need to generate the unique temporary filenames in my application using c++ (WINRT/Metro). As I see, Win32 API `GetTempFileName` is marked for use on desktop only.

What is its equivalent for metro style apps?

Comment: Why would you call the Win32 API instead of the C# method that likely for this profile.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: System.IO.GetTempFileName does not exist in the WinRT .NET Profile. It was suggested in this thread an alternative http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1c053a5d-83f0-4e61-aed1-c2c6cadcb30a/

Comment: You should also read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758319%28v=win.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yo can achieve this by saving a file in temporary storage, and naming them via a GUID.  Example:

```
// Get temporary storage folder    
var tempFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;

// generate unique filename
var filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
StorageFile myFile = await tempFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```